# What's reason of that LIKE query didn't disable the composite Index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, b-tree-index

Here is my table struct

```
CREATE TABLE t(
c1 CHAR(1) not null,
c2 CHAR(1) not null,
c3 CHAR(1) not null,
c4 CHAR(1) not null,
c5 CHAR(1) not null
)ENGINE InnoDB CHARSET UTF8;

alter table t add index c1234(c1,c2,c3,c4);
```

When I use `explain select * from t where c1='1' and c2 >'2' and c3='4'`, the explain result shows that the `key_len` is only 6, i.e., only c1 and c2 is active.

However, after executing `explain select * from t where c1='1' and c2 like '2%' and c3='4'`, the result shows that the `key_len` is 9, all index is active.

I think the `LIKE %` query is a range query like `<` and `>`, whereas, the occurrence of `LIKE %` didn't influence the use of index after it.

Comment: LIKE allows to use index while searching by prefix. If you'd use `and c2 like '%2'` or `and c2 like '%2%'` you'd obtain another result..

Comment: You should try it with `CHAR(2)`. It might be smart enough to figure out that `2%` is the same as `2` for a `CHAR(1)` column.

Comment: @Akina :),I know '%2' is different from '2%'. My confusion is in the `B-Tree` struct; if a certain index column used in the form of a range query of `where`, why the later indexes are still active? Wouldn't it break the search process of the later indexes?

Comment: @Vatev :), Nice Idea, but there is no change after I replace it with `CHAR(2)`

Comment: `c2 like '2%'` is equal to `c2 >= '2' AND c2 < '3'` - it's obvious that this form may use index.

Comment: @Akina. Actually, I want to know why the index of 'c3' is active?(I know c2 is active), For example, `where c1='1' and c2 >'2' and c3='4'`, in this sentence, the use of indexes are (c1, c2), the index of c3 is inactive.

Comment: It's faster to use the index as compact table copy. I.e. server checks all 3 subconditions by the index then retrieves according rows from the table - this is faster then check 2 conditions by the index and then scan the table body for 3rd condition checking. This is similar to covering index improvement.

Comment: The two variants are different, [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html) explains the difference.

Comment: @Vatev :), thanks for your help.

Comment: @Akina :), thanks for your help.